# RecyclerView multiple layouts causes ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, classcastexception

programmers! I try  to make multiple `itemType`  for  `RecyclerView` and  I have already found similar issues, but they  haven't helped me to solve my one.

Code:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements AdListener {
protected List<FoodData> foodDataList;
protected Context context;
protected String image_url, food_title, id;
protected int ingredients_count;
protected Intent intent;
private static final String FROM = "c172x172";
private static final String TO = "c480x180";
private HashMap<Integer, String> titleMap = new HashMap<>();


public RecyclerAdapter(List<FoodData> food, Context context) {
    this.foodDataList = food;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            return new MainViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_add, parent, false));
        case 2:
            return new AdditionalHolderl(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false));

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {

        case 0:
            MainViewHolder m_holder = (MainViewHolder) holder;
            image_url = foodDataList.get(position).getRecipe_image_url();
            image_url = image_url.replaceAll(FROM, TO);
            food_title = foodDataList.get(position).getRecipe_text();
            if (titleMap.containsKey(position)) {
                m_holder.title.setText(titleMap.get(position));
            } else {
                titleMap.put(position, food_title);
                updateTextViewUI(m_holder.title, food_title);
            }

            id = foodDataList.get(position).getRecipe_id();
            ingredients_count = foodDataList.get(position).getRecipe_ingr_count();

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(image_url)
                    .into(m_holder.food_picture);

            m_holder.title.setText(food_title);
            m_holder.ingr_count.setText("Количество ингридиентов: " + ingredients_count);
            m_holder.look.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    intent = new Intent(context, FoodAppearance.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", foodDataList.get(position).getRecipe_id());
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            m_holder.food_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    intent = new Intent(context, FoodAppearance.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", foodDataList.get(position).getRecipe_id());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            return;
    case 2:
            AdditionalHolderl new_holder = (AdditionalHolderl) holder;
            new_holder.lol.setText("Text");
            return;
        default:
            break;

    }


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return foodDataList.size();
}

private void updateTextViewUI(final TextView textView, final String title) {
    new Handler(context.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(title);

        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2 * 2;
}


public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected ImageView food_picture;
    protected TextView title, ingr_count, look;
    protected LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public MainViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        food_picture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.food_picture);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ingr_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ingr_count);
        look = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.look);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);


    }

}

public class AdditionalHolderl extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView lol;

    public AdditionalHolderl(View view) {
        super(view);
        lol = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lol);

    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, new LogCat:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
                                                            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
                                                            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
                                                            at be.motti.uzb.RecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.java:80)
```

In this line:

```
  Picasso.with(context)...
```

Tried to remove/comment Picasso's implementation, but then next element goes `null` and causes `NPE`

**EDIT**

I have `debugged` it, and have found that all `View`s in `MainViewHolder` are `null`? Why Are they? They were not when I used single `ViewHolder`
I would be very happy if you help  me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onBindViewHolder()` appears to be the wrong way round when it comes to the view type. In `onCreateViewHolder()`, `MainViewHolder` is returned for position `0`, and `AdditionalViewHolder` for position `2`.

Swap `0` and `2` around in `onBindViewHolder()` and it should work.

Comment: @PeterParker Check that `food_picture` isn't `null` in `onBindViewHolder()` (i.e. `Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "true if food_picture null: " + (m_holder.food_picture == null));`...if it is, then double check that the `id` you provide in your `ViewHolder` exists.

Comment: I have `debugged` it, and have found that all `View` in `MainViewHolder` are null? Why Are they? They were not when I used single `ViewHolder`

Answer (score 0):

Try

> instanceof

keyword to get it right!

Do the followoing in your onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder,int position)

```
    if(holder instanceof AdditionalViewHolder)
{
//Do your stuff for AdditionalViewHolder
}else{ //Do your stuff for MainViewHolder}
```

Answer (score 0):

invert your switch for onBindViewHolder. that is, on case 0, handle MainViewHolder. That should solve the problem.